# Scrolling towards the destination of an animated moving element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, transform, masonry, packery

I'm currently creating a page using [Packery.js](http://packery.metafizzy.co/)

Right now, I have a pretty straightforward grid of 4 tiles wide and when a tile is clicked it enlarges, kinda like in this demo:
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/pgVQLz

However in my case the tiles are paintings, and since they are enlarged according to screen size when clicked, I need to scroll the viewport a little bit to nicely make it fully visible and in the center of the screen.

The problem is that because Packery animates the movement of the tile, I cannot simply use:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: Y});
```

Because in that case it will scroll towards the position it was in before the animation.

What would be the best way to fix this?

I've been stuck at this for several hours now. I even tried:

```
var x = $(this).css('transform');
```

...to find the offset of the transform animation, but next to being a dirty dix I couldn't even find the values...

Thanks!

Comment: apparently there is a **[`layoutComplete`](http://packery.metafizzy.co/events.html)** event that I think you can use. It gets called when _all positioning transitions have completed_. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using now, but I want the scrolling to happen alongside with the enlargement of the picture instead of afterwards. If the animations happen after oneanother the page feels a bit slow.